# How do I Reload Sheet by Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that I want to reload the page every time my script is finished running. Is there a script line that does this?

Comment: Hi! Why do you want to reload the page? What exactly are you trying to refresh?

Comment: Just run `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush())